# Cannot save as csv using QFileDialog.getSaveFileName

Tags: qfiledialog

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
fileName = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Save",os.getcwd(),"CSV Files (*.csv)")
if fileName:
    with open(fileName, "w") as file:
        file.write(df)
```

I am tring to save my dataframe to csv using QFileDialog instead of df.to_csv, but this doesn't work

Comment: Are there any errors that show up?

Comment: @Fletchius I am using a pyqt5 window so, it only returns' Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)'

Answer (score 0):

```
fileName = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Save",os.getcwd(),"CSV Files (*.csv)")
print(fileName)
```

this returns strings in tuple, first is path

you should write:

```
fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Save",os.getcwd(),"CSV Files (*.csv)")
```